# Is there a standard approach to implement vertical scrolling that will work seamlessly across regular and mobile browsers?

Tags: css, scroll

I have a need to implement vertical scrolling inside a audio-player in my site.  I have done it in the simplest way possible (in my opinion).

I have kept a constant height for the window and made overflow 'auto':

```
overflow: auto;
height: 333px;
```

It works fine in all versions of IE, Firefox, Chrome that I could get to test with. (in Windows OS).  It gives me a little scroll bar in the right side.

[image: Scroll in regular browsers]

In mobile (touch) browsers, i don't see the scroll bar as a separate entity.  I can touch one of the list items and drag up or down.  This scrolls the list.  The problem is, this way of scrolling gives a good experience in some mobiles and very poor experience in other mobiles.

Ex: In iPhone (Safari), it worked great.  In Samsung Galaxy (Firefox), it was very poor.  It was even worse in the native browser which I guess is Opera.

Touch-wise, i think, both phones are good.  But when it comes to this scrolling function, there is a difference in the usability.  And the worst part is that I cannot test this unless I have the device with me.

Is there a standard approach to make scrolling seamless across regular and mobile browsers?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The best scrolling experience I've had in my mobile device (iPad 1) is to do it exactly how you have it - just using the browser's native touch-drag to scroll. Although many browsers approach it differently, the standard way presently seems to be native - even if it is less than ideal at times (for a while 2 finger scrolling was the way...the very irritating way).